# Repeated video in AVMutableComposition result

Tags: ios, swift, avmutablecomposition

I'm trying to combine one videotrack and two audiotracks with AVComposition. It works ok (I have some video with two audiotracks as the result), but there is a strange problem: when I'm trying to play resulting video in player, it's playing for, like, 18 seconds and after that it starts from the beginning!

After that it's ok.

Why it could happen?

videoAsset, audioAsset, and audioAsset2 are just AVAssets initialized with URL.

```
//Creating AVMutableComposition

var mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    try! videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration),
            ofTrack: videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0],
            atTime: kCMTimeZero)


let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: 0)
        try! audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration)),ofTrack: audioAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], atTime: kCMTimeZero)

//the first audiotrack is very short, it's just an overlay for the first several seconds               

let audioTrack2 = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: 1)
    try! audioTrack2.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), ofTrack: audioAsset2.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], atTime: kCMTimeZero)

//this one is the main audiotrack for the video. its length slighly bigger than video duration, so I use videoAsset.duration here

//Player

self.videoitem = AVPlayerItem(asset: mixComposition)

player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.videoitem)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
                self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                    selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:",
                    name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
                    object: player.currentItem)

    player.volume = 0.7
    player.play()
```